# Add an attribute to an HTML tag

Tags: java, groovy

How want to convert an html input string, which is the from of:

`String tag = "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit\"/>";`

to

`"<input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit disable\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>"`

Is there any possible Java or Groovy way to do this?

For example:

```
String convert(String input) {
 //input: <input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit\"/>
 //process the input string
 //processedString: <input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit disable\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>
 return processedString;
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter may I know the reason

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/281863/22815).

Comment: What did you try so far?  You may use XML library or HTML specific library like jsoup.

Comment: More context needed. Is it in a String or what? If so, what does the String contain - the whole document or just this one tag? Is there any reason not to use DOM objects instead of Strings? As it is, this question is too broad.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Yes it is String, the string contains only this tag.

Comment: I downvoted because it's clear that any programming language can perform this conversion. Need more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WillieWheeler, can u give me hint on how to proceed, without any third party library

Comment: @WillieWheeler, in you answer are not processing the `input argument`, rather simply returning the expected output.

Comment: @Suganthan Your question doesn't really imply any processing is needed. Please try and reword your question?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make the point that the problem is underspecified. :-/ You need to post an attempt, or at least more context, so we know what you think a solution looks like.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the OP wants to be able to edit or add (and possibly remove) attributes from a string containing a tag. It is actually pretty interesting question because using an XML library for such a simple string could be an overkill, but more simple solution will likely to be error-prone unless some limitations are put on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most generic way I can think of:

```
public static String editTagXML(String tag,
        Map<String, String> newAttributes,
        Collection<String> removeAttributes)
        throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException,
        TransformerException {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(tag)));
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NamedNodeMap attrs = root.getAttributes();
    for (String removeAttr : removeAttributes) {
        attrs.removeNamedItem(removeAttr);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> addAttr : newAttributes.entrySet()) {
        final Attr attr = doc.createAttribute(addAttr.getKey());
        attr.setValue(addAttr.getValue());
        attrs.setNamedItem(attr);
    }
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(result));
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    String tag = "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit\"/>";
    String edited = editTagXML(tag, new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("class", "cssSubmit disable");
        put("disabled", "disabled");
    }}, new ArrayList<>());
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(edited);
    System.out.println("Time: " + time + " ns");
    start = System.nanoTime();
    tag = "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit\"/>";
    editTagXML(tag, new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("class", "cssSubmit disable");
        put("disabled", "disabled");
    }}, new ArrayList<>());
    time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("Time2: " + time + " ns");
}
```

It is ugly, huge, complicated, throws a lot of checked exceptions and mixes up the attributes order which may or may not be important. It is probably not how it should be done. It is also pretty slow.

Here is the output:

```
<input class="cssSubmit disable" disabled="disabled" type="submit"/>
Time: 86213231 ns
Time2: 2379674 ns
```

The first run is probably so slow because it takes a while to load up the necessary libraries. The second run is surprisingly fast, but my PC is pretty powerful too. If you put some constraints on your input (like, attribute values are only quoted with `"`, and no `"` in attribute values and so on), there will be probably a much better way to do it, like using regular expressions or maybe even simple iteration.

For example, if your input always looks like that, this could work just as well:

```
    start = System.nanoTime();
    edited = tag.replaceFirst("\"cssSubmit\"", "\"cssSubmit disable\" disabled=\"disabled\"");
    time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(edited);
    System.out.println("Time3: " + time + " ns");
```

Output:

```
<input type="submit" class="cssSubmit disable" disabled="disabled"/>
Time3: 1422672 ns
```

Hmm. The funny thing is, it's not that faster.

OK, but what if we want a more generic solution, but still simple enough? We could use regular expressions:

```
private static final Pattern classAttributePattern
        = Pattern.compile("\\bclass=\"([^\"]+)\"");
public static String disableTag(String tag) {
    Matcher matcher = classAttributePattern.matcher(tag);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Doesn't match: " + tag);
    }
    int start = matcher.start();
    int end = matcher.end();
    String classValue = matcher.group(1);
    if (classValue.endsWith(" disable")) {
        return tag; // already disabled
    } else {
        // assume that if the class doesn't end with " disable",
        // then the disabled attribute is not present as well
        return tag.substring(0, start)
                + "class=\"" + classValue
                + " disable\" disabled=\"disabled\""
                + tag.substring(end);
    }
}
```

Note that *usually* using regular expressions for XML/(X)HTML is *extremely* error-prone. Here is a non-exhaustive list of example inputs that could break the code above:

- `<input type="submit" class="cssSubmit disable " disabled="disabled"/>` - this will break because of the space before the quote;
- `<input type="submit" class='cssSubmit disable' disabled="disabled"/>` - this will break because single quotes are not expected by our code;
- `<input type="submit" class = "cssSubmit" disabled="disabled"/>` - this will break because there are spaces around `=`;
- `<input title='this is an input with class="cssSubmit" that could be changed to class="cssSubmit disable"' type="submit" class="cssSubmit" disabled="disabled"/>` - this will break because there is attribute-like text in another attribute's value.

Each of these cases can be fixed by modifying the pattern in some way (although I'm not sure about the last one), but then you can find yet another case when it breaks. So this technique is best used for the input that was generated by a program, rather than written by a human, and even then you should be careful about where the input for that program came from (it could easily contain attribute values like in the last example).

Comment: I respect your time, It seems like solution would too complex, I have consider several other factors like performance, usage of new libraries etc.. So I would rethink for another way to solve the issue. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Suganthan, what you should do first is to figure out your actual task. There's a huge difference between "add _an_ attribute to _an_ HTML tag" and "add the disabled attribute to a tag that looks like this". In the latter case, it could be as simple as `tag.replaceFirst("\"cssSubmit\"", "\"cssSubmit disable\" disabled=\"disabled\"")`.

Comment: you are using `jsoup` library class for this right?

Comment: Nope, just the standard Java library.

Comment: Ok I got it, the latter one seems much more easier and shorter

Comment: @Suganthan, only it won't work, for example, if the input has a different class attribute or it is formatted differently: `class='cssSubmit'` (with single quotes). You really need to clarify your requirements first, and clearly document them in the comments or Javadoc of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76851/discussion-between-suganthan-and-sergey-tachenov).

Comment: @Suganthan it's easier in groovy with a proper XML parser (see other answer)

Comment: @tim, that's exactly the point I was trying to make when providing a list of various bizarre ways it can fail in. But if you generate those tags yourself, so they are _guaranteed_ to have a certain form, then it _could_ be safe. I still wouldn't do it, though, as it gives me the creeps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in groovy:

```
String tag = "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"cssSubmit\"/>"

tag = new XmlSlurper().parseText(tag).with { x ->
    x.@class = 'cssSubmit disable'
    x.@disabled = 'disabled'
    new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { delegate.out << x}.toString()
}​
```